# How to duplicate related row for all master record

Tags: sql, t-sql, master-detail

I want to duplicate related row(s) in detail table for all rows of master.

For example:
Master table is:

```
PK   | Data
--------------
1    |  A
2    |  B
3    |  C
```

Detail table is:

```
PK    | FK     | Data
---------------------
1     | 1      | AA
2     | 1      | BB
3     | 1      | CC
```

and after the sql query is run:
Detail table is:

```
PK    | FK     | Data
---------------------
1     | 1      | AA
2     | 1      | BB
3     | 1      | CC
1     | 2      | AA
2     | 2      | BB
3     | 2      | CC
1     | 3      | AA
2     | 3      | BB
3     | 3      | CC
```

Comment: Can you explain how your master table and your detail table are related to each other? Is the FK in the detail table the PK from your master table?

Answer (score 1):

What you have given in the output is a Cross Join (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) and is generally "A Bad Idea".

Normally you would want to have at least one WHERE clause to restrict the data the is being returned, as the tables grow larger the result that you will get will grow quickly. The amount of rows returned will be the product of the sizes of the two tables.

Comment: Thanks, But this isn't my answer. I want copy detail rows for all master row.

Answer (score 1):

I think you detail table is like this(FK data should be `1,2,3` instead of `1,1,1`)

```
PK | FK | Data
---------------
1  | 1  | AA
2  | 2  | BB
3  | 3  | CC
```

You can query like this:

```
SELECT detail.* FROM master, detail
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99176/3)

Comment: I want copy 3 detail rows for other rows of master!

Comment: @HajAhmad If in detail table there is no FK for 2 & 3 then how can you fetch it from detail?

Comment: `code`insert into detail values( 1,aa),( 1,bb),( 2,aa),( 2,bb)

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into Detail(PK, FK, Data)
select D.PK, C.PK, D.Data
from Detail as D
  cross join (select PK
              from Master as M
              where M.PK <> 1) as C
where D.FK = 1
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/77230)

Answer (score 0):

```
</pre><code>
Create database:
USE [t]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[detail](
    [PK] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FK] [int] NULL,
    [Data] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_detail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PK] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[detail]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_detail_master] FOREIGN KEY([FK])
REFERENCES [dbo].[master] ([PK])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[detail] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_detail_master]
GO

//Create master table:

USE [t]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[master](
    [PK] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Data] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_master] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PK] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO


//Create detail table:

USE [t]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create procedure [dbo].[douplicate]
 @source int,
 @des int
as
begin
insert into dbo.detail(FK,Data)
SELECT     @des,dbo.detail.Data
FROM         dbo.detail INNER JOIN
                      dbo.master ON dbo.detail.FK = dbo.master.PK
where fk=@source                  
end

//Insert values:

insert into master values 
  ('A'),
  ('B'),
 ('C')

insert into detail  values
  (1,'AA'),
  (2,'BB'),
  (3,'CC')

//Create procedure and solotioanswer:

USE [t]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create procedure [dbo].[douplicate]
 @source int,
 @des int
as
begin
insert into dbo.detail(FK,Data)
SELECT     @des,dbo.detail.Data
FROM         dbo.detail INNER JOIN
                      dbo.master ON dbo.detail.FK = dbo.master.PK
where fk=@source                  
end
</code></pre>
```